# Extract id from generated file name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extract the user id from generated file name. First I wrote them as :

```
id_timestamp.ext
```

And now I need to read the list and filter out of the list of files only specific user with the id owned files.

I think doing

```
substring(fileName, id.length)
```

is to wonky.

Is there a way to do it ? Should I use a regex?

Comment: What is `id`? What are you doing with the result of the `substring` operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you built your filenames like

```
const filename = `${id}_${timestamp}.ext`;
```

and assuming that your ids and timestamps don't contain timestamps (so that the generated filenames are unambiguous), you can check whether a file belongs to a certain user via

```
filename.startsWith(`${id}_`)
```

Notice you need to include the underscore, just `filename.startsWith(id)` will lead to false positives as your ids are unlikely to be prefix-free.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to solve your problem.

```js
const filename = 'id_timestamp.ext';
const regex = /^(\w+)_timestamp\.ext$/;
const id = filename.match(regex)[1];
```

This works by matching the id part with a capturing group. This group can than be used as the id as it only contains the id part.

Alternatively you can use a combination of `indexOf` to find the position of the underscore and `substring` to get the first part up to that position.

```js
const filename = 'id_timestamp.ext';
const id = filename.substring(0, filename.indexOf("_"))
```

If the id always has the same length then you even can get rid of the indexOf part.

Answer (score 1):

If your `id` will always be the first and you are generating as `id_timestamp.ext` pattern
I suggest the following approach to extract out `id` from the file name

```js
const fileName = `1234_file.txt`;
const arr = fileName.split("_");
const id = arr[0];

console.log(id) // "1234"
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be making this too simplistic but ...

`getId = function(s){  s = s.substring(this,s.lastIndexOf('.'));  s = s.substring(this,s.lastIndexOf('_')); return s; }`

seems to solve the problem if the desired format stays true.
`s.substring(this,s.lastIndexOf('.')` isolates the extension out and
`.lastIndexOf('_')` will search the remaining last `_` occurrence in the string.

here's a smaller version of the recyclable function

`getId = function(s){ return s.substring(this,s.substring(this,s.lastIndexOf('.')).lastIndexOf('_')); }`

and if this is happening on load here is a direct

`filename.substring(this,filename.substring(this,filename.lastIndexOf('.')).lastIndexOf('_'));`

Examples with either function option below

`var filenameA = 'id_timestamp.ext';`

`var filenameB = 'testID_123654789.ext_';`

`getID(filenameA)` or `getID(filenameB)`

Results

filenameA results : **id**

filenameB results : **testID**